# Assembly language a2004 symbol type conflict

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

i am really new to assembly and i am running an example code but it gives me the error "2004 symbol type conflict". i tried looking at the other questions in stack overflow that are related to this same problem but i don't understand them. anyone have a fix for it in visual studio 2019??

this is the code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
message   db "Hello world!", "$"

.code

main   proc
   mov   ax,seg message
   mov   ds,ax

   mov   ah,09
   lea   dx,message
   int   21h

   mov   ax,4c00h
   int   21h
main   endp
end main
```

Comment: The error is on this line:  mov   ax,seg message

Comment: @AdrianMole nope already looked into that. I don't know how to apply that to visual studio 2019

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same code and exactly the same error message.

Comment: It is the problem is that I don't know how to apply the fix for it.

Comment: pax's answer seems to be saying that modern MASM might not be capable of making legacy 16-bit object files anymore, so they're recommending an older toolchain if you really want to make obsolete DOS executables instead of making code for the OS you're running on.

Comment: The dupe target seems specific to masm32. I suspect answering the question for VS would involve finding out where the binaries are to compile the code manually (`ml.exe` and `link16.exe`) and/or a method to change the IDE's behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes . Even with new versions of MASM (>=8.0) you can still assemble with /OMF (instead of /COFF) and it will generate object files that can be used by a 16-bit segmented linker. The problem is that with MASM >= 8.0 they stopped shipping a segmented linker. If one copies the link16.exe from MASM32's SDK you can use it with Visual Studio but the linker program and options will have to be modified for the project.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ah, I see.  If you made a `.com` instead of `.exe`, you wouldn't need a linker (if the assembler can output a flat binary directly like NASM can), so that might be a way to avoid needing a 16-bit linker, with different source that didn't use `mov ax, seg ...`.  But this question is reporting an A2004 error, which is assemble time, not link time, right?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks. Perhaps it would be good to edit pax's answer with those little extra details about why `/coff` is a problem.  If there's a good answer to the full question for Visual Studio, perhaps it could get posted there, despite that Q&A supposedly being about MASM32 specifically which does come with older MASM and a 16-bit linker.  That would put both versions in an easy-to-find place.  Answering this one would require links both ways for people whose search landed at one but are using the other toolchain, or aren't aware of the difference.

Comment: I think this is a separate question as it involves using the IDE to modify the linker and linker options after copying link16.exe over from something like MASM32 SDK. I'd do it but I don't have VS2019 on me at this time and I can't remember all the menus and options off the top of my head lol. Yes, this one is related to the other but  I don't think a VS specific answer is suitable under the other answer.